# Magento2 : Something about category_form.xml

Tags: magento2, category, xml, forms

I want to add a input only can be put in a url like "http://www.google.com", I do it like this:

```
    <field name="url">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Url</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="validate-url" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

but the validate does no work, it can be save whatever I put what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
```

node needs to be inside the

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
```

If you try to add new content to an adminhtml ui-component it is always a good choice to look on a ui-component XML of the Magento2 core.